# Radio button no cambia el valor de los boleanos

Tags: java, android, android-studio, radiobutton

Estoy con un programa de Android Studio en Java, en el que quiero que cuando pulse un botón, de un RadioGroup, me cambie una variable a positivo.

La cosa es que no lo hace, y no entiendo el motivo.

Aquí está el XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Categorias_Chat">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:text="Categoría para los chats:"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="172dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbReli"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Religión"
            tools:ignore="OnClick" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbTiempo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tiempo Disponible"
            tools:ignore="OnClick" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbCiudad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ciudad"
            tools:ignore="OnClick" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbExtra"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Extraescolares"
            tools:ignore="OnClick" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbEsc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tipo de Escuela para el hijo"
            tools:ignore="OnClick" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Categoria"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ver Usuarios"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Y aquí está el java (las variables las declaro encima):

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categorias_chat);

        rbCiudad = findViewById(R.id.rbCiudad);
        rbTiempo = findViewById(R.id.rbTiempo);
        rbEsc = findViewById(R.id.rbEsc);
        rbExtra = findViewById(R.id.rbExtra);
        rbReli = findViewById(R.id.rbReli);
        envCate = findViewById(R.id.btn_Categoria);

        if (rbReli.isChecked()){
            reli = true;
        }else if(rbTiempo.isChecked()){
            tiempo = true;
        }else if (rbCiudad.isChecked()){
            ciudad = true;
        }else if(rbExtra.isChecked()){
            extra = true;
        }else if(rbEsc.isChecked()){
            esc = true;
        }

        System.out.println("rel "+reli);
        System.out.println("tiempo "+tiempo);
        System.out.println("ciudad "+ciudad);
        System.out.println("extra "+extra);
        System.out.println("esc "+esc);
```

Debajo tengo más código, pero este no se ejecuta por culpa de que no se cambian las variables boleanas, ya que son if de "si la varaible x es true, haz esto".

He puesto unos Systems prints para que me muestre el valor de las variables boleanas, y todas aparecen en "false", aunque pulse en el Radio Button.

¿Por qué?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para detectar cuando un elemento dentro de un `RadioGroup` fue seleccionado, debes usar `OnCheckedChangeListener`, incluso dentro puedes distinguir cual de tus `RadioButton` fue seleccionado a partir de su id :

```
myRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            switch(i) {
                case R.id.rbReli:

                    reli = true;

                    break;
                case R.id.rbTiempo:

                    tiempo = true; 

                    break;
                case R.id.rbCiudad:

                    ciudad = true;

                    break;
                case R.id.rbExtra:

                    extra = true;

                    break;

            }
        }
    });
```